# Datepicker is not working for dynamically create fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have created a text field datetimepicker using jquery, but when i create field dynamically on this dynamic textbox datetimepicker is not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#acd').on('click', '.dateyear', function() {
    $('.dateyear').datepicker({
      format: "yyyy",
      viewMode: "years",
      minViewMode: "years"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.14/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div id="acd">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="passyr[]" class="form-control dateyear">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what was the essuy or error when running code ???

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/hriziya/htnvo4rs/1/

Comment: Mention your plugin url, there are so many datepicker plugin out there

Comment: how do you create this textbox? can you paste the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not calling date picker dynamically. Need to call datepicker() dynamically. Mean after creating input box dynamically call

```
$('.dateyear').datepicker({
                    format: "yyyy", 
                    viewMode: "years", 
                    minViewMode: "years"
                 });
```

too there.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you initialise the datepicker ".dateyear" is not loaded so $ can't find ".dateyear" element so It can't bind datepicker with ".dateyear". when you click on text field It didn't show up datepicker. You need to initialise datepicker when your dynamic element attach to DOM structure.